# Why does CUDAFunctionLoad not accept character types (strings)?

Tags: cudalink

Why does `CUDAFunctionLoad` not accept character types (strings)? I want to load equations defined in an array (a list of equations) which is written in Mathematica and call them using `CUDAFunctionLoad`. It is very difficult to define the whole equation in cuda c/c++. Can anyone please explain. Is there is any other way to fix it?

```
 __device__ float f (float t, float x)
     { return (sin (x) + sin (t));} 

 __global __ void secondKernel (float out[2][5], float x[], float t, 
      float h, float end, int listSize) 
    {
     int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
     float k1, k2, k3, k4;
     int i = 0;
     do {
            k1 = h*f (t, x[index]);
            k2 = h*f (t + h/2.0, (x[index] + k1*h/2.0));
            k3 = h*f (t + h/2.0, (x[index] + k2*h/2.0));
            k4 = h*f (t + h, (x[index] + k3*h));
            x[index] = (k1 + 2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3 + k4)/6.0;
            out[index][i] = x[index];
            t = t + h;
            i++;
        } while (t <= end);
     }
    ";
start = 0.0; end = 4.0; h = 1.0; nsteps = (end - start)/h;

xarr = {4.0, 5.0}; listSize = Length[xarr];

secondKernel = CUDAFunctionLoad[secondKernelCode, "secondKernel",{{"Float"},{"Float"}, "Float", "Float", "Float", _Integer}, {2, 5}];

output = CUDAMemoryAllocate["Float", {2, 5}];

secondKernel[output, xarr, start, h, end, listSize];

outputarray = CUDAMemoryGet[output][[ ;; ]]
{{-0.16506, 1.28052, 1.36264, 0.622622, -0.539732}, {-0.522478, 
  0.740226, 1.47266, 0.598251, -0.575384}}
```

the above code is the Rungekutta 4 solution for the given differential equation **f'(x,t)=sin(x)+sin(t).**
To find the the solution we have to give the equation inside the c Code . Its fine if the equation is simple and only one.
 When there are multiple equations and the equations are complex it is difficult to redefine every variable inside the c code again because `CUDAFunctionLoad` doesnot accept this kind of input.It only accepts the list of numeric.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you are asking. What relationship do strings and equations have?  Also, `"Byte"` is a valid argument type, which provides a way to encode strings.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and reply @Szabolcs. Actually the general equations in mathematica contains mainy variables , so it requires for me to input the array of equations into the c code, rather defining again in c. I have tried with "Byte" type i am not sure whether its working.

Comment: What would you do with a *string* of a Mathematica expression in C?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sir, I want to input the above equation using `CUDAFunctionLoad` and the equation contains variables in which the return type to it must  be character or strings

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to construct C code as a string. `CForm` is a useful tool for simple expressions, but more complicated programming needs help. Here's an example of translating a `StateSpaceModel` into C:

Helpers to extract the parts of a discrete time state space model.

```
a[m_[{a_, b_, c_, d_}, p__Rule]] := a /; m === StateSpaceModel
b[m_[{a_, b_, c_, d_}, p__Rule]] := b /; m === StateSpaceModel
c[m_[{a_, b_, c_, d_}, p__Rule]] := c /; m === StateSpaceModel
d[m_[{a_, b_, c_, d_}, p__Rule]] := d /; m === StateSpaceModel
tsamp[m_[{a_, b_, c_, d_}, p__Rule]] := 
 SamplingPeriod /. p /; m === StateSpaceModel
```

A function to construct a list of C assignment statements.

```
assign[lhs_String, rhs_] := lhs <> " = " <> ToString[CForm[N[rhs]]] <> ";"
assign[lhs_Symbol, rhs_] := assign[ToString[lhs], rhs]
SetAttributes[assign, Listable]
```

Make a list of variables like {x1, x2, ...}. Omit the number if only one.

```
mkvars[root_String, n_Integer] := (root <> #) & /@ (ToString /@ Range[n]) // 
  ToExpression
mkvars[root_String, 1] := {ToExpression[root]}
```

Make a list of variable declarations.

```
varDecls[init_, decls__] := 
 "float " <> 
  stringRiffle[Map[initstring[init, #] &, Flatten[{decls}]], ", "] <> ";\n"
initstring[init_, s_] := ToString[s] <> init
```

Construct C code to implement a discrete time state space model, with input "u", output "y", state variables "x", temporaries "xt".

```
stateCode[m_StateSpaceModel] := 
 With[{
   a = a[m] /. {0. -> 0, 1. -> 1},
   b = b[m] /. {0. -> 0, 1. -> 1},
   c = c[m],
   d = d[m]},
  With[{
    x = mkvars["x", Length[a]],
    xt = mkvars["xt", Length[a]],
    y = mkvars["y", Length[c]],
    u = mkvars["u", Length[d[[1]]]]},
   varDecls["=0", x] <>
    varDecls["", xt, y, u] <>
    stringRiffle[
     Join[
      assign[y, c.x + d.u],
      assign[xt, a.x + b.u],
      assign[x, xt]],
     "\n"]]]
```

Given a model (not included here), you may then generate code as follows:

```
stateCode[someStateSpaceModel[...]]
```

Yielding, as a string:

```
 "float x1=0, x2=0, x3=0, x4=0, x5=0, x6=0;
 float xt1, xt2, xt3, xt4, xt5, xt6, y, u;
 y = 0.031127973531929903*u - 0.02101524984082605*x1 -
 0.035188225051206584*x2 - 0.1213134928462274*x3 + 
 0.3160616000095401*x4 + 0.010488819711376657*x5 + 
 0.2621918599112481*x6;
 xt1 = x2;
 xt2 = x3;
 xt3 = x4;
 xt4 = x5;
 xt5 = x6;
 xt6 = u - 0.08803437213024824*x1 + 0.805012011701874*x2 - 
 3.0263511390065165*x3 + 6.024518327556238*x4 - 6.727592601453252*x5 + 
 4.010120040702665*x6;
 x1 = xt1;
 x2 = xt2;
 x3 = xt3;
 x4 = xt4;
 x5 = xt5;
 x6 = xt6;"
```

You may then concatenate this string to other strings to make a complete definition for CUDALink.

Comment: The ``"SymbolicC`"`` package might be useful too